# Destructuring and initializing constructor properties

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to achieve something like this in Typescript?

```
class Coin {
  last_scraped: number;

  constructor(public { gecko_id: string, symbol: string }) {}
}
```

Where class `Coin` takes an object containing `gecko_id: string`, `symbol: string` and assigns them as public properties to the class instance?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do like this:

```
constructor(args: {gecko_id: string, symbol: string }) {
    return Object.assign(this, args);
}
```

Comment: That will assign all the properties of args to this

Comment: Clever. Can you do `this = {...args}` ? Or `return {...this, ...args}`

Answer (score 0):

One of two ways I can think of:
First, the caller needs to get the values from the object and pass them as parameters.

```
class Coin {
  last_scraped: number;

  constructor(public gecko_id: string, public symbol: string) {}
}
```

Second, do the work inside the constructor:

```
interface I {
  gecko_id: string;
  symbol: string;
}

class Coin {
  last_scraped: number;
  gecko_id: string;
  symbol: string;

  constructor(object: I) {
    this.gecko_id = object.gecko_id;
    this.symbol = object.symbol;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a function that will take any object and return a new object that has all the same fields plus a new field called `last_scraped` of type `number`.

```
type Coin<T> = { last_scraped: number } & T;

function newCoin<T>(T x): Coin<T> {
   return { last_scraped: 0, ...x }   
}
```